# Using php, prompt user to re-authorize at session timeout?

Tags: php, session-timeout

I'm working with using session to authorize users.  It works fine as long as they move between pages, and we've got the timeout set to two hours, so it usually won't be an issue.  However, with the users we work with, I can imagine them getting preoccupied after doing work on a single page, then letting it sit for two hours.  If the session times out, they lose the work, and I've already had testers unhappy with me because their session timed out (only 24 minutes then, though).

Is there a way to run a script when the session times out, so that I can at least ask the user to login again?  I know I can do it via javascript -- if I modify every single one of the more than 100 .php scripts used by the website.  But I have a single auth script, and if I could run it from there, it would be nice.

Thanks,

Sean.

Comment: @Breezer - cookies wouldn't be any better than using sessions. @Sean - I think you're really going to need to implement a Javascript solution if you want it to work without the page refreshing. On a side note, if you have 100 pages you have to edit, you might want to look at separating common sections of a page, e.g. header, footers and include those. That way you only have to edit one file instead of 100.

Comment: Yeah, some things are already separated out and I use includes.  But I had been told the authorization side was going to be done a completely different way, so I'm having to put it in after most of the site has been written.  Oh well.

Comment: of course cookies would be better you could set it to expire after a day and it would decrease the performance of the server at all which what sessions might do

Comment: It seems to me like the problem isn't that your session times out, it's that you don't autosave a draft first.

Comment: If you have more than 100 accessible PHP scripts then you're doing it wrong.  If they all have copy 'n pasted code at the top of them to handle authentication and sessions, then you're doing it *very* wrong.  All of this should be in one place, e.g. have a single controller that all requests go through that handles authentication.  Easier to maintain.  Harder to screw up.

Answer (score 0):

Prompting the user using PHP or any other server-side scripting language is not possible without a refresh.  You're basically asking your server to serve something that the browser didn't request, which is why its not possible.  But as you already know you can use JavaScript to get the job done.

#### EDIT:

*The following is not set in stone or true in all cases it just might apply to your situation.*
To run a script when a session times out you would have to :

- Test for a session time out.

  - To test for a session time out, a script has to be executed.

    - For a script to be executed, it is has to be requested.

Comment: That's what I had understood.  But I saw something about creating a session handler that could redirect what happened on a session-destroy.  I thought perhaps there was an answer there.

Comment: @Sean, redirection is the simple part, but you still need to execute a script to `session_destroy()` or detect session destruction.